Website working in local server, not working when built with npx vite build
I'm building a website and I'm encountering a problem trying to deploy it. Following the Vite docs here, I installed Vite and three.js and completed my site. Now, when I run npx vite build, the site stops working entirely, with 60 new errors per second when I try opening it with npx serve. My code is hosted at my Github repo here.
HTML:
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NeuroCatalyst</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <base href="/">
    <script type="importmap"> {
            "imports": {
                "three": "/node_modules/three/build/three.js",
                "three/addons/": "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/",
                "three/nodes": "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/nodes/Nodes.js"
            }
        }
        </script>
    <script defer type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Major+Mono+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

JS:
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js';
import { OutputPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/OutputPass.js';

File Structure :

My localhost Vite server runs as expected, but when I ran npx vite build, following the instructions in the docs, the site stopped working as expected, with the three.js render in the background failing. Many errors are occuring, including Uncaught TypeError: cc is undefined index-5LnSVFjA.js:3999:3205 and Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties index-5LnSVFjA.js:3999:3205. I tried using a CDN to import the module instead of Vite, but when I tried this approach, I got the error Loading module from “http://localhost:3000/node_modules/three/build/three.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)..

I tried following the installation guide to serve the project through npx vite had to go through my own set problems not basically same as yours but I would like to suggest some learnings which may be of some help to you.
Importing three.js as import * as THREE from 'three';  was the problem as vite was not able to import the package from node_modules folder to its own .vite folder in node_modules, we need to use destructured import statement to make that work which is something like import {Scene, Camera, etc...} from 'three';
Side point you wouldn't even need importMap now after that you can directly use it from locally installed package.
